# Beamer, Tikz - control fontsize and paragraph of a callout

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, callout

I have been working with this very simple callouts package from tikz on beamer. I am having some issues though in controlling the writing inside the callout. 
I want to be able to make paragraphs inside the text and change the font size of the text. How can that be done?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}%


\usepackage[beamer,customcolors]{hf-tikz}
\usepackage{tikz}


\usetikzlibrary{shapes.callouts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,arrows,decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage[english]{babel}


\begin{document}



\begin{frame}{Dummy slide}
\begin{itemize}

\item{\textbf{Dummy:} Dummy, \tikz[remember picture] \node (a) {\vphantom{X}}; Dummy, dummy, dummy  }
\item{\textbf{Dummy:} Dummy }
\item{\textbf{Dummy:} Dummy }

\end{itemize}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\path<2> (a.east) ++(-5,1) node[anchor=west,rectangle callout,fill=red!50,opacity=.5, callout absolute pointer={(a.mid)}]  {Some dummy text here. Paragraph. Some more dummy text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change width of node by `text width`.

Change font style by `font`.

Don't load a package more than once.

I prefer using only one `\usetikzlibrary`, or use that command for each library (like `\usepackage`)

Sample code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[beamer,customcolors]{hf-tikz}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,arrows,decorations.pathreplacing,shapes.callouts}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Dummy slide}
\begin{itemize}
\item{\textbf{Dummy:} Dummy, \tikz[remember picture] \node (a) {\vphantom{X}}; Dummy, dummy, dummy  }
\item{\textbf{Dummy:} Dummy }
\item{\textbf{Dummy:} Dummy }

\end{itemize}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\path<2> (a.east) ++(-4,1) node[anchor=west,rectangle callout,fill=red!50,opacity=.5, callout absolute pointer={(a.mid)},text width=5cm,font=\bfseries\footnotesize]  {Some dummy text here. Paragraph. Some more dummy text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]